# Parse-Server delete class with Mongodb

Tags: windows, mongodb, parse-server

How to delete class from mongodb?

ps. I'm using the mongodb 3.0 on windows with windows power shell.

Answer (score 1):

I found that answer above does not answer it 100% if you do that it will still show up in the parse dashboard. If you delete the record in the `_SCHEMA` collection in mongodb the class will no longer show up in the parse dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your question right:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/ if you want to remove all documents from a collection (i.e. class)

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.drop/ if you want to remove the whole collection (i.e. class)

There are also useful examples for each method in the MongoDB documentation.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes you got right it works perfectly. now the problem is that i need to automatize it in power shell because if i launch "mongo.exe -pwd mydb db.mycollection.remove" it connects to db and the script stucks and doesn't read the next commands

Comment: I'm no Windows user, but I think you should just start mongo.exe without additional commands. You will get a prompt then where you can enter as many commands in a row as you like. https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/client/